# beanshell inner class

Tags: java, beanshell

i wanted to use my java code as beanshell script but beanshell throws Exception saying class not found in namespace. Isn't there inner class in beanshell or does it have any other usage?

my script looks like here:

```
.......
.......
java code
.......
.......
MyClass m = new MyClass(); //Error here: MyClass not fount in namespace



class MyClass {

}
```

i use the inner class in script, which i declare in the script.

Thanks,
Bilal

Comment: Bilal, it would be very helpful to see your code, in order to find out what's the problem with it. BTW Beanshell supports inner classes and (since v2.0) anonymous inner classes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a silly answer here but could it be that the MyClass definition needs to be *above* its usage in the file?  Doesn't bean shell process scripts linearly?

A quick look in the docs doesn't spell this out but tests of the following script certainly works fine for me:

```
class MyClass {
}
MyClass m = new MyClass();
```

Comment: it didn't work. i have found another way without using inner class. but this is 2. time that i ran away from inner class. i have read many times that beanshell accepts inner class but it never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Class definition is not supported by BeanShell.

You can use BeanShell inner class syntax to implement an interface:

```
    x = new MyInterface() {
        overriddenMethod() {
          // ....
        }
    }

v = x.overriddenMethod();
```

Or

```
    overriddenMethod() {
       //.....
    }

    // 'this' is a object of whatever Foo expects 
    //
    new Foo(this);
```

In your case I think you are better off going with the scripted object approach:

```
myClass() {

// methods ...

return this;

};

m = myClass(); // new instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information: the *anonymous inner class **as argument*** can not use, so you need to assign your implementation to a variable. (In JMeter)

Not works:

```
object.setContext(new SomeInterface(){
  //implement methods
});
```

Works:

```
SomeInterface ctx = new SomeInterface(){
    //implement methods
});
object.setContext(ctx);
```

Hope it will help out someone.